# Griddler gem throwing exception while parsing an incoming email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sendgrid, griddler

I have integrated Sendgrid incoming parse Webhook API, and it is correctly posting the email object to my rails app. On app I'm using griddler gem to catch and do further processing of email data. But I'm getting following exception:

```
Sent mail to chandan@exmaple.com (77.6ms)
F, [2014-11-14T17:48:05.851336 #24799] FATAL -- :
NoMethodError (undefined method `process' for #<EmailProcessor:0x0000000a2ad5f0>):
  griddler (1.1.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:19:in `public_send'
  griddler (1.1.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:19:in `process_email'
  griddler (1.1.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:4:in `block in create'
  griddler (1.1.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:3:in `each'
  griddler (1.1.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:3:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
```

Where as I have the process instance method in /mailer/email_processor.rb

```
class EmailProcessor
  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
    puts "initialized Email Processor\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" # Should see this line in log
  end

  def process
    user = User.find_by_email(@email.from[:email])
    puts @email.inspect and return if user.blank?

    puts "############### @email = #{@email.inspect}###############\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
  end
end
```

Here is config/initializer/griddler.rb

```
Griddler.configure do |config|
  config.processor_class = EmailProcessor
  config.processor_method = :process
  config.reply_delimiter = '-- REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE --'
  config.email_service = :sendgrid
end
```

Here is the version of gem I'm using:

```
#Process incoming mail from sendgrid smtp server
gem 'griddler', "~> 1.1.0"
gem 'griddler-sendgrid', "~> 0.0.1"
```

This is based on documentation available on [griddler github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/blob/master/app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb)

Can anyone please help me with what I'm missing here. Also, why I don't see following line in log ?

```
"initialized Email Processor\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Following is the line to define route

```
mount_griddler
```

EDIT: As far as I know, rails doesn't add any such class directly.
Strangely I'm able to see the 'process' method available for 'EmailProcessor' class in 'rails console':

```
2.1.4 :005 > x = EmailProcessor.new(1)
initialized Email Processor\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
 => #<EmailProcessor:0x007fc6ae5aee08 @email=1>
2.1.4 :006 > x.methods
 => [:process, :blank?, :present?, ...
2.1.4 :014 > EmailProcessor.instance_methods(false)
 => [:process]
```

Thanks

Comment: Could there be another `EmailProcessor` class in your codebase? it looks like you don't subscribe that class you think you do...

Comment: No such existing class. To be double sure, searched in whole codebase again. I don't think rails has some inbuilt class with same name. Please see the update above. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the code you tried in the edit to inside the `Griddler.configure` block

Comment: 2.1.4 :020 > Griddler.configuration
 => #<Griddler::Configuration:0x007fc6b361c8b8 @processor_class=EmailProcessor, @processor_method=:process, @reply_delimiter="-- REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE --", @email_service_adapter=Griddler::Sendgrid::Adapter>

Comment: No, I meant adding `x = EmailProcessor.new(1)` and `puts x.methods` inside the configuration block, and see what it prints out

Comment: I'll have to edit the gem source code for that. May I know what do you want to check by doing that?

Comment: Why is it in the gem? it is in `config/initializer/griddler.rb`... What I'm trying to establish is whether there might be another class which is present in the context of the `configure` block, and not available in `irb`...

Comment: ohk.got you now. I thought you are saying for [griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/blob/master/app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb) gem source code. Here is the output: `$ rails c
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
initialized Email Processor

process
blank?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was, the `EmailProcessor` class was not being loaded with rails application startup. Adding following lines to `application.rb` did the magic:

```
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/mailers/email_processor.rb)
```

NOTE: You'll need to restart your server, every time you make changes to email_processor.rb.

Thanks to Joel Oliveira (Author of [Griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler)) to responding to my personal email and pointing out the issue :)